Apache timeout every minute disconnect my websocket on port 443
I have a websocket is running on Apache port 443.  I noticed from my web socket client it always disconnect every minute from the server, then it re-connect.
When I test this on my local machine without Apache, I don't see this disconnect behaviour. I know this is due to Apache timeout.
My question: How can I configure Apache to prevent the disconnect timeout behaviour on my web socket.
Here's my apache virtual host configuration:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName mydomain.com
 
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all -SSLv1 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:aNULL:eNULL:EXPORT:DES:RC3:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA
  
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
  </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)    ws://localhost:5122/$1 [P,L]

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>    


Something (web server, proxy, cdn, load balancer, whatever you use) is likely configured to time out.

I'm using AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2.   There's no load balancer or private network.

A work around for now, I add a timeout in Apache virtual host to 30 minutes.

I wonder if there's a configuration that no more timeout the web socket server.

You could not use apache.

You're correct @Evert, however I don't want to have a separate server to run my web socket alone.  I'm using Golang to build my web socket, however I do have a website as well that host on the same server.  That's why I'm using Apache, just to share the resources.  Absolutely, I can have a new linux box that listen on port 443.
